# Django URLConf for former forum URL

Tags: django, django-urls, python-2.x

I am tryimg to add content to a URL previously served by forum software. The URL is
    `/portal/forums/showthread.php?t=12345`

I have this in my urlconf, but it's not working:

```
url("^portal/forums/showthread.php?t=12345", thread),
```

I am just matching the whole string to a single view for now, but a way to pass the topic ID as an argument would also be handy. (Hopefully all the old URLs similar enough to match, without any funky querystrings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access `GET` (Query string) parameters like this:

```
def myview(request):
    t = request.GET.get('t')
    #rest of the code.
```

The GET parameters should not be a part of the URL.

Your URL then would look like this:

```
url("^portal/forums/showthread.php", thread), #You might want the $ sign at the end.
```

Comment: Thanks, I wrote up a "post-fetcher" to get the posts from the DB from the ID in the query string and the URL acts the way I intend.